# What's the proper name for the evaluation function?

Tags: terminology

What do we call the (proper-class) function $$\mathrm{eval}(*,*)$$ such that for all functions $g$ and all $x \in \mathrm{dom} \;g$ we have $\mathrm{eval}(g,x) = g(x)$ ? I looked up 'evaluation function' but it seems to be a [concept in game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_function) as opposed to the concept I'm looking for.

Comment: So what if there's a clash? "Normal function" has a meaning in set theory and in probability theory. I can assure you, the two notions do not coincide.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't care if there's a clash, but I can't get more information on the function until I know its standard name.

Comment: What sort of information would you like to find?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, in particular, I'm wondering if we can get away with only one $\mathrm{eval}$ function. Like, can I write $\mathrm{eval}(\mathrm{eval},(f,x))$ ? This sort of thing doesn't work in ZFC as I'm sure you're well aware, but maybe in other systems.

Comment: What other systems?

Comment: In lambda calculus, the eval function would make sense, but would be trivial.  In particular, we would say that $$\text{eval}(g,x)=[\text{eval}(g)](x)=g(x)$$ That is, "eval" would register as the identity function on any function.

Comment: Alternatively, you could define $$\text{eval}(x,g) = [\text{eval}(x)](g) = g(x)$$ That is, we would write $$\text{eval}=\lambda x.[\lambda f.[f(x)]]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common name I've seen for the function that applies a function to an argument is "[apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply)". However, I've also seen "eval" and several other names.

In a programming languages context, the name "apply" is fairly standard, although its exact semantics varies significantly between languages. "eval" in this context is more commonly used to refer to a function that parses and evaluates an expression from a string or abstract syntax tree, e.g. $\mathrm{eval}(``\ 2+3+1+1") = 7$ (note the quotation marks indicating a string of characters).

Comment: I see. From what I gather from that Wikipedia page, it appears that $\mathrm{apply}$ and $\mathrm{eval}$ are used quite differently in the programming language community. In particular, if $2+3+1+1$ is a multiset of natural numbers, then we might write: $\mathrm{eval}(2+3+1+1) = 7$. But we certainly would not write $\mathrm{apply}(2+3+1+1) = 7$.

Comment: I have added some information about this point to my answer.